# Системные вызовы Linux (Kali). Что означает NULL адрес который передается системному вызову brk в качастве аргумента?

Tags: syscall

Изучаю Ассемблер Nasm. Начал с самого стандартного "Hello World"а, и начал изучать каждую строку, есть вопрос насчет системных вызовов, прочитал документацию системного вызова и там написано что brk меняет размер сегмента данных, я сохранил лог strace, там brk принимает NULL значения в качестве аргумента... ниже фото

Что это значит ? что за NULL адрес принимает brk системный вызов ?

И еще один вопрос. Насколько я понял после "=" указывается значение возвращаемого значение системного вызова, в документации написано что brk возвращает одно из двух значений, 0 в случае успеха и 1 если какая-то ошибка, так у меня возвращает 0x5561ea0bb000, это значение 0 ? тоесть без ошибок выполнился системный вызов brk ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открываете маны и читаете. https://ru.manpages.org/brk/2
Возвращаемое значение при аргументе NULL (это почти всегда просто 0) - верхный маркер окончания доступной памяти. Обычно оно используется для определения доступной памяти для процесса